# Tkinter withdraw function inside button hides window from beginning

Tags: python, tkinter, button

My target is to create two windows. Window1 is opening at the beginning including a button and window2 is hidden. If I press the button I would like to hide window1 and show window2.

To do so I've created a small function and want to execute this function by pressing the button.

```
from tkinter import *

window1 = Tk()
window2 = Tk()
window2.withdraw()

def change_windows():
    window2.deiconify()
    window1.withdraw()

Btn1 = Button(window1, text="Show window2", command=change_windows())
Btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)

window1.mainloop()
window2.mainloop()
```

Problem is that the only thing that opens when I run the program is window2. It looks like the function is already executed without activating the button.

When I  delete the command function inside the button like this:

```
from tkinter import *

window1 = Tk()
window2 = Tk()
window2.withdraw()

def change_windows():
    window2.deiconify()
    window1.withdraw()

Btn1 = Button(window1, text="Show window2")
Btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)

window1.mainloop()
window2.mainloop()
```

..then window1 is opening and window2 is hidden. I am a beginner but I don't get what is the issue here.

Comment: It should be `command=change_windows`, not `command=change_windows()`.

Comment: Also, having 2 `mainloop()`s simply won't work as `mainloop` enters an infinite event loop.

Comment: Also, it's not generally advisable to have two instances of `Tk`. If you need more windows than the root, `Toplevel` is the better choice.